# React WYSIWYG editor with Material UI components support

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tinymce, wysiwyg

So I'm building a dashboard that allows clients to write some text with a WYSIWYG editor and publish it so it is available in an online reader.

Previously, I integrated TinyMCE as my text editor and it works well. It generates HTML from the text and formatting the user inputs. Now, I need to allow clients to be able to add some Material-UI components such as an ExpansionPanel to their content (by maybe clicking a button in the text editor toolbar).

I stumbled upon [mui-rte](https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte) that allows adding custom components the way I want but it appears to only generate a draft-js format which I'm unfamiliar with and will not be backwards compatible with HTML strings that have already been generated by clients.

My question is, how do I generate an HTML string in the format below with a WYSIWYG editor

```
<div>
 <h1>this is some text</h1>
 <ExpansionPanel></ExpansionPanel>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are aware of the draft js semantics you can write a small transpiler which takes the input from draftjs and converts that to HTML

Comment: @harshitpthk I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

there is a module called draftjs-to-html. In order to get html from wysiwyg editor you could write something like this.

```
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';

console.log(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
```

convertToRaw comes from draft-js editorState.getCurrentContent() comes from state change event in the editor which is documented in wysiwyg documentation.